# Engine stalls if giving gas (just for about 20 seconds after startup)

Tags: idle, peugeot, throttle-position-sensor, throttle-body

When I start my Peugeot 106, it will idle fine, but if I give gas it will stall. If I give just a bit of gas, after about 20 seconds the engine starts to run properly. I unmounted and cleaned the Throttle body and the Idle air control valve, but the problem is still exactly the same.

here are some things I noticed:

1. Happens just in hot days and when car was turned off for hours
2. A couple of times I had random erratic idle episodes

I think it is a problem with the MAP sensor or the Throttle position sensor but I don't know how to test it and I would like not to buy random parts.

Car model:
Peugeot 106 1.1
TU1JP (HFX)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! For anyone who cares, the [**TU1JP (HFX)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peugeot_106#Petrol_Engines) appears to be covering the 2000-2003 model years.

Comment: @Rhinoted: To "give gas" sounds odd to me - false friend? Are you from Germany? I may be mistaken though, not a native speaker myself ...